# Overload Index Operator in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to overload the index operator in Scala?
If yes, what would the scala version of this c++ example look like?

```
class Foo {
  int data[7];
  ...
public:
  int& operator[](size_t i) { return data[i]; }
  int  operator[](size_t i) const { return data[i]; }
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The index operator in scala is (), and you can define a method which looks like it. You need to define an apply method.

```
scala> class Foo(v: String) { def apply(i: Int) = v(i) }
defined class Foo

scala> val f = new Foo("foobar")
f: Foo = Foo@c3dd7e

scala> f(3)
res3: Char = b
```

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not possible to overload the index operator, `[` and `]` are reserved by the language for specifying type information (List[String] for example) and so are unavailable for that use. What you can use is the `apply` function. The closest equivalent to what you have in your c++ example would be:

```
class Foo {
    val data = Array.ofDim[Int](7)
    //...
    def apply(i : Int) : Int = data(i)
    //...
}

//Usage :
//var f = new Foo
//val aNumber = f(0) 
//aNumber == f.data(0)
```

The `apply` function in scala is simply some syntactic sugar, if you have it defined then `f(0)` gets expanded to `f.apply(0)` behind the scenes. If you want to be able to use statements like `f(0) = 4` you can do that as well, by means of the related `update` function.